# After removing non-number characters from a string and using the int() function on it, error occurs

Tags: python, string, file, int

The specific line is

```
b = int(a.translate(None, "\t<,"))
```

a is a string which contains `"\t<56,000"`. When I print the result of the translate operation I get "56000", but when it gets to the `int()` line, it gives me an error saying

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

as if the string I gave it was null for some reason. Is there something I'm doing wrong? (also I'm reading the string in from a txt file if that changes anything)

Here is the source code: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?ktali8dc6nd03i6)

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This works for me in 2.6.6.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. Could you include a complete, runnable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: This breaks in Python3 and gives a somewhat similar error.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.5.5, which I just realized doesn't support "None" as an argument in translate. However I've tried doing this several different other ways, like using the replace function, and I get the same error

Comment: Double-check that `a` is in fact the string you think it is.  This is the only reasonable explanation for none of these various methods working.

Comment: @user1200397: the problem must lie somewhere else. show us more code.

Comment: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?ktali8dc6nd03i6) 
Here is the full code and source text file, you'll have to change the path.
@hop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in addition to all the strings you think you are getting, you also end up with a few strings consisting only of "\t", which is then turned into empty strings by the string conversions.

Adding an additional clause to the if-test when testing for empty strings solves this:

```
if (i != " ") and (i != "") and (i != "\t"):
    (...)
```

instead of:

```
if i != " " and i != "":
    (...)
```

Also, consider using parenthesis for clarity...

Comment: +1 for spotting the problem. -1 for the awkward solution. You can remove all whitespace by doing `i = "".join(i.split()` then just test `if i:`. By the way, `i` is a ludicrous name for a text value.

Comment: Yeah I actually figured this out a few hours after posting, thanks for the help though! This is my first day using Python, still finding it really weird.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter`:

```
b = int(filter(lambda character: character.isdigit(), a))
```

For Python 3:

```
b = int(''.join(filter(lambda character: character.isdigit(), a)))
```

Comment: May not matter, but `translate` is quite a bit more efficient.

Comment: Updated. That should be a bit faster than the regex.

Comment: @Blender: `filter(str.isdigit, a)` looks nicer, imho.

Comment: @hop - It looks nicer, but will choke on unicode.  [`operator.methodcaller('isdigit')`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) is an alternative but it isn't much nicer than the lambda.

Comment: @F.J: granted. depends on the specific case, i guess.

Comment: @F.J Wouldn't `unicode.isdigit` solve the problem in both cases?

Comment: @Blender, By the way, "12³".isdigit() is true while "12³".isdecimal() is false.

Comment: How about `int(''.join(c for c in a if c.isdigit()))`?

Comment: @MichaelMior: That'll work as well. I just like using `lambda`.

Comment: @Blender Fair enough. Although using generator expressions is slightly more efficient.